# refinement of partition clarification

Tags: real-analysis

My book defines a refinement of a partition $P$ as such

Given a partition $Ρ$ of the interval $[a, b]$, another partition $P^*$ of $[a, b]$ is called 
a refinement of $Ρ$ if each partition point of $Ρ$ is also a partition point of $P^*$. If $Ρ = 
\{x_0, ..., x_n\}$ and $P^*$ is a refinement of $P$, then for each index $i\geq 1$, the partition points  of $P^*$ that belong to the partition interval $[x_{i-1}, x_{i},]$ define a partition $P_i$, of the interval  $[x_{i-1}, x_i]$.

What I don't get is what $P_i$ really means? I have an example say that $P=\{[0,\frac{1}{2}],[\frac{1}{2},\frac{3}{4}],[\frac{3}{4},1]\}$ and $P^*=\{[0,\frac{1}{2}],[\frac{1}{2},\frac{3}{5}],[\frac{3}{5},\frac{3}{4}],[\frac{3}{4},1]\}$ where $P^*$ is a refinement of $P$. But I don't get how $P_i$ applies here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$P_2$ is the partition of $[1/2,3/4]$ given by
$$
P_2=\Bigl\{\Bigl[\frac12,\frac35\Bigr],\Bigl[\frac35,\frac34\Bigr]\Bigr\}.
$$

$P_1$ and $P_3$ consist of just an interval.

Comment: And then $P^*=P_1\cup P_2\cup P_3$?

Comment: That is correct.

Comment: @JuliánAguirre, Is $P^*\supseteq P$? If yes, how?

Comment: @DhamnekarWinod The partition is the collection of points, not the collection of intervals. Then $P=\{0,1/2,3/4,1\}$ and $P^*=\{0,1/2,3/5,3/4,1\}$.